# Implementing Queue system using List FHIR Resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to use List FHIR resource to implement a queue system.

Are there any existing implementation guides on this?

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Not published by HL7.  You might have better luck reaching out on the Skype implementers list.  (Instructions on how to join are on the [FHIR wiki](http://wiki.hl7.org?title=FHIR).)  However, the List resource does seem like the appropriate one for your use-case.